# ARM: Complex variable with array of objects

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I can't read from the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#variables if it is possible to create an array of complex objects. I think the "Variable-complex-type-value" is a bit vague.

Is it possible to create something like

```
    {
    "variables" : {
       "appsettings" : [ 
                {"name" :"1","value" :"v1"}, 
                {"name":"2","value" :"v2"}
        ]
}
```

I want to be able to reference this in the appsettings of siteconfig, like this

```
{
... 
   properties:{
      "siteconfig" :{
          "appsettings" :"[variables('appsettings')]"
     }
  } 
... 
}
```

Is this even possible?

I am not in a position right now where I can try this at a computer so that is why I am asking here.

Comment: Yes it is possible and you should try ;-)

Comment: @Thomas thanks :) actually I kind of knew it was but I wanted to be sure. I know it is possible in the parameter section, but I haven't read anywhere that it is possible in the variable section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

To create multiple instances of a variable, use the `copy` property in the variables section.

You create an array of elements constructed from the value in the input property. You can use the `copy` property within a variable, or at the top level of the variables section. When using `copyIndex` inside a variable iteration, you must provide the name of the iteration.

```
"copy": [
      {
        "name": "top-level-object-array",
        "count": 5,
        "input": {
          "name": "[concat('myDataDisk', copyIndex('top-level-object-array', 1))]",
          "diskSizeGB": "1",
          "diskIndex": "[copyIndex('top-level-object-array')]"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "top-level-integer-array",
        "count": 5,
        "input": "[copyIndex('top-level-integer-array')]"
      }
    ]
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#variable-iteration).

Comment: I have read about the copy but I am not going to need it. I am explicitly asking for if it is possible to create an array of complex objects in the variables section.

Comment: Yes, you can. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/building-blocks/extending-templates/objects-as-parameters).

Comment: Aaaah. firstProperty is doing a complex object in the variables section and using an array :)